# Check if 4 columns exists in 2 columns from another table

Tags: mysql

Trying to check the contents in `4` columns in `Players` and see if they exist in `2` columns of `Users`, `First Name` and `Last Name` respectively.

Players:

```
First_Name    Last_Name    First_Name_2      Last_Name_2 

Alpha          Beta              Charlie       Delta
Eve            Fred              NULL          NULL
Casper         Dhorn             Alpha         Beta
```

Users:

```
   First Name       Last Name 

    Alpha            Beta
    Charlie          Delta
    Eve              Fred
    Casper           Dhorn
```

Tried many queries, this one i got closest to....

```
SELECT *
FROM   Players
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Users 
                   WHERE  Players.First_name = Users.First_Name
                   OR   Players.First_Name_2 = Users.Last_Name )
```

However it return:

```
First Name    Last Name

Alpha          Beta
Eve            Fred
Casper         Dhorn
```

My aim is have a query produced that will have 2 columns, `first_name` and `last_name` and will have the rows from players where the players `first_name`, `first_name_2` and `last_name`, `last_name_2` are  equal to the Users `first_name` and `last_name`

A visual representation:

```
First Name          Last Name

Alpha                Beta
Charlie              Delta
Eve                  Fred
Casper               Dhorn
```

The issue is trying to compare the next column, `first_name_2` to the users `first_name` as it simply ignores these columns and only focuses on the first column, `First_Name`

Comment: Table_1 contains 4 columns, it's impossible that the query returns 2 columns.

Comment: The query in the question has a reference to `Table_2.Column_3`, but the example data for `Table_2` doesn't show a `Column_3`. The specification of the resultset to be returned is vague, subject to many possible interpretations. Without a specification, we're just "trying" things. To what? See if we happen upon a resultset we like?

Comment: now you edited your question but the query can't be working since `Table2` doesn't contain `Column_3`. please give more (precise) information and the expected result.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Updated it - do i need to add anything else? Apologies for this also everyone

Comment: now your query isn't valid again because you are using `Players.First_name` but don't use the `Players` table on `FROM` or join.

Answer (score 0):

"trying to check" doesn't tell us what *result set* the query should return.

We are going to interpret the specification as returning the row from (the table unfortunately named) `Table_1`, along with columns that indicate whether matching row(s) were found in (the table with the similarly ill-fated name) `Table_2`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT t.column_1
     , t.column_2
     , t.column_3
     , t.column_4 
     , ( SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table_2 t2 
                          WHERE t2.column_1 = t.column_1
                            AND t2.column_2 = t.column_2
                       ) c12
       ) AS match_1_2
     , ( SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table_2 t2 
                          WHERE t2.column_1 = t.column_3
                            AND t2.column_2 = t.column_4
                       ) c34
       ) AS match_3_4
     , ( SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table_2 t2 
                          WHERE t2.column_1 = t.column_3
                       ) c3
       ) AS match_3
     , ( SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table_2 t2 
                          WHERE t2.column_2 = t.column_4
                       ) c4
       ) AS match_4
  FROM `Table_1` t
```

The `match_1_2` column in the resultset will contain a value of 1 if at least one  matching row is found in `Table_2`. If no matching row is found, the column will contain a 0 (zero). Similarly, `match_3_4` will contain a 1 if a match is found, otherwise 0.

We can perform all manner of checks, checking that just one column matches, demonstrated by the match_3 and match_4 expressions.

If we want to restrict rows returned,  we can add a HAVING clause.  If we want rows that don't have a match on column_3 and column_4 (where a match is not found), then

```
 HAVING NOT match_3_4
```

If we want to return only rows that have both matches on 1&2 and 3&4,

```
 HAVING match_1_2
    AND match_3_4
```

---

Note that this query satisfies just some interpretations of the requirement. The specification given in the question is nebulous i.e. isn't clear about what resultset should be returned.